# Thank you for downvoting poor challenge questions

Tags: discussion

I noticed that over the past few days, the community has gotten a lot more aggressive about downvoting poor challenge questions. I think this is what needs to happen and will eventually lead to a site full of high-quality puzzles, which is what it looks like we as a community have decided we want. Thank you for doing so!

Specifically, what I've noticed is that on the homepage right now, almost all questions are either highly upvoted or heavily downvoted. The downvoted questions are the kinds of assumption puzzles and poorly-constructed puzzles we don't want anymore, while the upvoted questions really are high quality.

**This post is meant as a thank you, feel free to discuss if you think this is a positive step in the right direction or not**

Comment: Add me to the confused list. What on earth are you trying to say with this post? That we're working on the definition of quality? Yes, but that's visible from the threads that discuss quality. That downvoting is good? That seems a very pessimistic way of looking at things. What is this meta thread about? What are we supposed to discuss?

Comment: @rand I edited what I assume he meant in.

Comment: @rand warspyking is right. I don't think there's much to discuss. I just noticed that we're starting to enforce the decisions we've made about puzzle quality, and that makes me optimistic about how we're going to do as a community. =)

Comment: Until everything came to a head, I was unaware that abstaining was hurting this site. The downvote hammer *will* be swinging the next time I'm perusing.

Comment: @Mazura Right so. Just keep in mind that a down-vote is best accompanied with some (constructive) criticism.

Answer (score 1):

I agree for the most part with what you are saying. I too believe that this is one step towards a higher-quality community. I just wish that the people with good ideas out there that cannot structure their puzzle the same way could be taught how to structure them in a more professional way.

Comment: I suspect that the people who really want to be a part of our community will stick around for long enough and experiment with writing questions enough that they will, in fact, learn. ;-)

Comment: I see your point. :)

Comment: This is something we can strive to do - when you see a gem in the rough, it may be helpful to comment suggesting how things can be cleaned up and improved.